# MySql store date as Date or BigInt (Epoch)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, epoch

When working with MySql, is it better practice to use the `DATE`,`DATETIME`,`TIMESTAMP` datatypes for storing date and time or a `BIGINT` datatype with an epoch time stamp?

What advantages do each have and what are the performance differences?

Comment: have you looked up any performance stats or done any research?  If so what is your current understanding so we can help with any holes in your understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Use `date` if you only need the date.
Use `datetime` if you need date and time.
Use `timestamp` if you need to version your records.
Use `epoch time` if you are working with that format and don't need dates before 1970.